# MKL support for Cross-platform c# development on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, intel-mkl

My system is Windows 10 pro, x64 architecture. 
MKL Version: 2019 Update5.

MKL Claims it support IA-32 and Intel 64 architecture, but did not specify if cross-platform support (x86_32 on x86_64) is achievable or not.

I built the custom dll (mkl.dll) successfully using the example 1 (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-in-your-c-program?page=1), but when I tried to register the dll to system, I got the following error. Any idea?

[RegSvr32 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3BH1.png)

Comment: Using regsvr32 is not sensible, it is not a COM server.  The library is made to be used from C or C++, doing in C# is not very practical.  The Math.NET library can wrap it: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/MKL.html

Comment: @ Hans Passant Thanks for the insight. I tested Math.Net yesterday, and the performance is really bad. As the developer pointed out, the "Integral transform" module in Math.NET is not developed as MKL native library is. I'm seeking a high fft performance .Net library. So far, fftw seems to be the best, but I want to test the performance of the MKL in warpper as well.